# Get rank in a score table

Tags: mysql

how to rank in myqsl?

sample code:

```
SELECT
    contestant_tbl.contestant_num,
    contestant_tbl.fn,
    contestant_tbl.ln,
    tally_j1_tbl.c1_score + tally_j1_tbl.c2_score AS j1_total,
    tally_j2_tbl.c1_score + tally_j2_tbl.c2_score AS j2_total
FROM
    contestant_tbl
LEFT JOIN tally_j1_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j1_tbl.contestant_num
LEFT JOIN tally_j2_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j2_tbl.contestant_num
GROUP BY
    contestant_tbl.contestant_num
```

i wanted to have an additional column total and rank.

[image]

Comment: Provide a fiddle with some sample data (or at least CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO scripts). Show desired result for this data. And specify MySQL version.

Comment: What is the reason for to use GROUP BY in a query when none aggregate function is used in it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT
    contestant_tbl.contestant_num,
    contestant_tbl.fn,
    contestant_tbl.ln,
    tally_j1_tbl.c1_score + tally_j1_tbl.c2_score AS j1_total,
    tally_j2_tbl.c1_score + tally_j2_tbl.c2_score AS j2_total
    j1_total + j2_total AS total,
    RANK () OVER ( 
    ORDER BY total DESC
    ) rank

FROM
    contestant_tbl
LEFT JOIN tally_j1_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j1_tbl.contestant_num
LEFT JOIN tally_j2_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j2_tbl.contestant_num
GROUP BY
    contestant_tbl.contestant_num
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot guess your database structure according to your question. However, there are couple of noticeable issues. 
Please take a look at the corrected query (rankings included):

```
set @num = 0;
SELECT
    contestant_tbl.contestant_num,
    contestant_tbl.fn,
    contestant_tbl.ln,
    sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0))   AS j1_total,
    sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))  AS j2_total,
    sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))  AS total,
    @num := @num + 1 as pos 
FROM
    contestant_tbl
LEFT JOIN tally_j1_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j1_tbl.contestant_num
LEFT JOIN tally_j2_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j2_tbl.contestant_num
GROUP BY
    contestant_tbl.contestant_num
ORDER BY 
    sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0))  +  sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))
```

1. Numerical values that can be NULL should be coalesced prior sum opperation. (e.g. **coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0)**).
2. Your query contains group by, but doesn't contain any aggregate function. I assume that **sum** should be used.

Ranking is achieved by utilizing MySQL variables. It is for older MySQL versions. MySQL 8 introduced RANK function so it is easier and cleaner:

```
SELECT
        contestant_tbl.contestant_num,
        contestant_tbl.fn,
        contestant_tbl.ln,
        sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0))   AS j1_total,
        sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))  AS j2_total,
        sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))  AS total,
        RANK() OVER (
          ORDER BY sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0))  +  sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))
        )  as pos 
    FROM
        contestant_tbl
    LEFT JOIN tally_j1_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j1_tbl.contestant_num
    LEFT JOIN tally_j2_tbl ON contestant_tbl.contestant_num = tally_j2_tbl.contestant_num
    GROUP BY
        contestant_tbl.contestant_num
    ORDER BY 
        sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c1_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j1_tbl.c2_score, 0)) + sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c1_score, 0))  +  sum(coalesce(tally_j2_tbl.c2_score, 0))
```